# 非同期通信の終了タイミングでテーブルをreloadDataしたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm

MVVMでの実装方法について質問です。

ModelでAFNetWorkingを使用し、JSONを取得しています。
AFNetWorkingの非同期通信が終了したタイミングでViewのテーブルをreloadDataしたいのですが、MVVMの場合ModelからViewを操作することは無いと認識しています。
この場合のViewを更新する方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
// Model
[manager POST:testAPI
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {

     // レスポンスをDBに登録

     // TODO: DB登録後、Viewの更新処理を実行したい


 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
 }];
```

＜追記＞
【delegate】
<s>Viewでmodel.delegate = self としてもAFNetWorkingのブロックスが実行されるときにはnilとなってしまいます…</s>
Modelのインスタンス作成でミスしているだけでした。

【blocks】
View→ViewModel→Modelの流れなので......

```
// View
    [_viewModel sampleMethod1:^{
        [self refresh];
    }];

// ViewModel 
- (void) sampleMethod1:(void (^) (void)) refreshView {
    [_model sampleMethod2:^{
    refreshView();
}];

// Model 
- (void) sampleMethod2:(void (^) (void)) refreshView {
    ..........

    [manager POST:testAPI
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
     {

         // レスポンスをDBに登録する処理を実行
         .......

         // TODO: 上記DB登録処理後、Viewの更新処理を実行したい
         refreshView();

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
     {
     }];
```

}
となり、VからVMに渡した処理をさらにMに渡して処理する事になり冗長な気がしました。
もっと綺麗な書き方があると思うのですが、分かりません…。

＜追記２＞
Blocksの場合の綺麗な書き方は分かりませんが、delegateで実装できそうでした。

Answer (score 4):

Model内のメソッドの処理が完了したことを知らせる方法は2つほどあります。
(非同期処理が含まれている場合を書きます)

- delegateを自作して、処理完了後にdelegateのメソッドを呼び出す
- Block構文をメソッドの引数に持たせる

各特徴ですが、

【delegateの特徴】

- ソースのネストが少なくなる
- optional指定することで、処理を譲渡される側で受け取り処理を書かなくても済み、複数箇所で利用する際にソースが荒れない
- ソースを見たときに、処理を直列的に追えない

【Block構文の特徴】

- ソースの処理を直列的に追いやすい(&直列的に処理を書ける)
- Model内のメソッドが減る(delegateではメソッドを必要分 追加する)
- そのModelを呼び出す側で定義するオブジェクトの数が減る
- ソースのネストが深くなる

といったところです。
初めはどちらかの利用に統一されても良いとか思います。

私の場合は両方使いますが、
使い分けとしては、

- 連続した非同期処理ではない→delegate
- 連続した非同期処理がある→Block構文

としている場合が多いかもしれません。

書き方としては、
【delegateの書き方】

Model.hを下記として

```
// デリゲートを定義
@protocol WebClientDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSuccess:(NSDictionary *response);
- (void)didFailure:(NSError *error);

@end

@interface Model : NSObject

/// デリゲート先で参照するためのプロパティ
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<ModelDelegate> delegate;
....

@end
```

Model.mを下記内のメソッドで

```
- (void)sampleMethod
 {
        [manager POST:testAPI
           parameters:parameters
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
        {

            // レスポンスをDBに登録

            // TODO: DB登録後、Viewの更新処理を実行したい
            NSDictionary *result = "何らかの結果"
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSuccess:)]) {
                [self.delegate didSuccess:result];
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFailure:)]) {
                [self.delegate didFailure:error];
            }
        }];
}
```

【Block構文の書き方】

```
- (void)sampleMethod:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success 
             failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
 {
        [manager POST:testAPI
           parameters:parameters
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
        {

            // レスポンスをDBに登録

            // TODO: DB登録後、Viewの更新処理を実行したい
            NSDictionary *result = "何らかの結果"
            success(result);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            failure(error);
        }];
}
```

となります。

以上、少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 簡単にですが、ソースコードも追記しました

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。追記しましたのでよければ確認お願いします。